# Remove link after last Ampersand of URL in PHP

Tags: php, url

So I see split is no good anymore or should be avoided.

Is there a way to remove the LAST Ampersand and the rest of the link.

Link Before:
http://www.websitehere.com/subdir?var=somevariable&someotherstuff&textiwanttoremove

Link After:
http://www.websitehere.com/subdir?var=somevariable&someotherstuff

Right now I am using this script:

```
<?php
    $name = http_build_query($_GET);
    // which you would then may want to strip away the first 'name='
    $name = substr($name, strlen('name='));
    //change link to a nice URL
    $url = rawurldecode($name);
?>

<?php echo "$url"; ?>
```

It takes the whole URL (all Ampersands included)...the issue is, the site the link is coming from adds a return value &RETURNVALUEHERE, I need to remove the last "&" and the rest of the text after it.

Thanks!

Robb

Comment: Where is this URL coming from? Is it in a string, or is the the current script's URI?

Comment: By the way, `split()` was long ago deprecated, but there are plenty of alternatives in `explode()` and `preg_split()`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it's stored as a string in $url...can I just explode the last & even if I don't know how many & there will be?

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of a url?

Comment: @Jack one specific one (keep in mind these are dynamically created): http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=USXdsD0kQ9I&offerid=251379.10001421&type=3&subid=0

Comment: @synergy989 And that should be stripped down to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `substr` and `strrpos`

```
$url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '&'));
```

Comment: I think he wants the position of the last ampersand.

Comment: @noko its the last parameter

Comment: What happens if there's no ampersand though?

Comment: @Jack, The OP indicates dealing with a known url, which always appends a param to remove. It's trivial to wrap the above statement in a conditional though, such as `if (strpos($url, '&') !== FALSE) { }`

Comment: Thanks @Crisp and everyone else, this baby worked like a charm.

Comment: Actually, I just realised the URL is generated from $_GET, so this can be done easier by just slicing the array.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is already $_GET, removing the last value pair could simply be this:

```
http_build_query(array_slice($_GET, 0, -1));
```

Comment: Hi Jack, looks great but I added it to the code and it doesn't seem to be working. You can see here: http://mediaortech.com/staging/redirect.php?link=http%3A%2F%2Fsunglasshut.com&post_id=100000851606175_478856125486408#_=_

Comment: @synergy989 Worked out a different approach which should be a lot easier than reverse engineering a url ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strrpos()` like

```
$url = substr($orig_url, 0, strrpos($orig_url, "&"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the Real URL, I was able to come up with this:

```
<?php

// The string:
$string = "http://www.websitehere.com/subdir?var=somevariable&someotherstuff&textiwanttoremove";

// get the position of the last "&"
$lastPos = strrpos($string, "&");

// echo out the final string:
echo substr($string, 0, $lastPos);
```